# Custom form Validation by Vuetify Showing Error _this.$refs[f].validate is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make custom validation with Vuetify. My Vuetify version is **1.11.3**. Here is my template. I set a ref to v-card according to [this  documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#custom-validation).

```
    <v-card ref="form">
        <v-card-text>
          <v-text-field
            ref="name"
            v-model="name"
            label="Full Name:"
            :rules="[() => !!name || 'Name is required']"
            :error-messages="errorMessages"
            required
            light
          >
          </v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            ref="email"
            v-model="email"
            label="Email Address:"
            :rules="[
              () => !!email || 'Email is required',
              () => (!!email && /.+@.+/.test(email)) || 'Email must be valid',
            ]"
            required
            light
          ></v-text-field>

          <VuePhoneNumberInput
            ref="phone"
            v-model="phone"
            color="black"
            dark-color="white"
            size="lg"
            default-country-code="BD"
            light
            required
          />
          <v-textarea
            ref="msg"
            v-model="msg"
            label="Message"
            :rules="[() => !!msg || 'Message is required']"
            light
          ></v-textarea>

        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn @click="sendForm"> Submit </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
```

I am trying to validate the form and textfields with their references.
This is my code:

```
 data() {
    return {
      name: null,
      email: null,
      phone: null,
      msg: null,
      submitStatus: null,
      formHasErrors: false,
      errorMessages: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    form() {
      return {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        phone: this.phone,
        msg: this.msg,
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    name() {
      this.errorMessages = ''
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sendForm() {
      this.formHasErrors = false

      Object.keys(this.form).forEach((f) => {
        if (!this.form[f]) this.formHasErrors = true
        this.$refs[f].validate(true)
      })
}
```

When I submit the button, It shows

> client.js?06a0:103 TypeError: _this.$refs[f].validate is not a
> function

I get following error. What is the wrong with that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommence using [V-form](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/) instead of v-card here.

Then you can check if your form is valid with the function `this.$ref.myForm.validate()` which returns a **boolean**

Here is a small example:

```html
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-form ref="myForm">
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            sm="7"
          >
            <v-text-field
              prepend-icon="mdi-tag-text"
              v-model="form.name"
              :rules="[
                 (v) => !!v || 'Name is requierd',
              ]"
              label="Name"
            />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-form>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        @click="check"
      >
        Check
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
```

And the script :

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    form:{
      name : ""
    },
  }),
  
  methods:{
    check(){
      if (this.$refs.myForm.validate()){
        //form is valid
      } else {
        //form is not valid
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```